# Use Green's Theorem to compute the value of the line integral $\int_{\gamma}ydx + x^2dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Use Green's Theorem to compute the value of the line integral $\int_{\gamma}ydx + x^2dy$, where $\gamma$ is the circle given by $g(t) = (\cos t, \sin t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

I have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma} Fdx + Gdy = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\sin t + \cos^2 t)dt = \bigg[\cos t - \sin^2t \bigg]_{0}^{2\pi} = (1-0) - (1-0) = 0
\end{align}$$

I get my answer as 0, but my textbook says the answer is $-\pi$.

---

I don't think I used the fact that $\gamma$ is a circle correctly, but not really sure what went wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: $dx$ and $dy$ are not $dt$, that's where you went wrong. $dx = x'(t)dt$ etc. Regardless, the problem does not ask you to compute the line integral directly, it asks you to use Green's theorem.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to review integration skills. $\int \cos^2 t dt \neq \sin^2 t$

Comment: "Use Green's Theorem". The integral is equal to $\iint_R \left(G_x - F_y \right) \, dx \, dy$, where $R$ is the region inside of the circle

Answer (score 2):

$d(ydx+x^2dy)=dy\wedge dx+2xdx\wedge dy=dx\wedge dy$. Green theorem implies that $\int_\gamma ydx+x^2dy=\int_{B(0,1)}dx\wedge dy=\pi$ the later is the area of the ball of radius $1$ in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

By Green's theorem, we have

$$ \iint_{\text{disk}} 2x-1 dA$$

The integral of the first term is $0$ because it is odd, and the region has symmetry across the line $x=0$. So we are left with an integral that equals negative the area of the circle, $-\pi$

Comment: Why is the integral of the first term 0? I don't understand the justification that it is odd and that the region is symmetric across $x = 0$. Can you expand the double integral over the region of the disk and dA?

Answer (score 0):

Made a change to polar coordinates, $x= r \cos \theta; y=r \sin \theta $ with $r∈[0,1]$ and $\theta ∈ [0,2 \pi]$ and as $dA=dxdy$,the Jacobian of the transformation $x=rcosθ$; $y=rsinθ$ is $r$ so $dxdy=rdrdθ$

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (2r \cos \theta-1) \, r dr \, d\theta = & \int_0^{2\pi} \Big[\frac{2}{3} r^3 \cos \theta-\frac{r^2}{2}\Big]_0^1 \, d\theta\\ = & \int_0^{2\pi} \Big[\frac{2}{3} \cos \theta-\frac{1}{2}\Big]_0^1 \, d\theta\\ = & \Big[\frac{2}{3} \sin \theta- \frac{1}{2} \theta\ \Big]_0^1=- \pi\\
\end{align}